# Using a Three-Tier Architecture with Sensitive Data

Tags: security, web, three-tier

I have heard thoughts that using a three-tier architecture is the best practice for web applications that need to be secured.

My understanding of this architecture is as follows:

- Web Tier Servers - Field requests and communicate with a middle layer for database communication. The database is completely walled off from the web server environment.
- Middle Tier Servers - Expose an API that will handle the retrieval and storage of all information. The web server communicates to this server to handle data operations.
- Data Tier Servers - Stores all of the user data. Allows communication from the middle tier, but not from the web tier

The other option is direct communication from the web server to the database. This communication would be done as a specific user who only had access that the application needed (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` on the necessary tables). This user, for example, wouldn't be able to delete records from the user table or drop tables.

The logic behind the three-tier approach being more secure is that if your web server is compromised, the attacker would only be able to get data in the same way that you can use your API.

My question: Is this type of approach necessary for a web application where potentially sensitive data is stored? All incredibly sensitive data would be encrypted at rest, but other personally-identifiable information would be stored in plaintext to allow searching.

If it is necessary, what is the best way to secure such an approach? Should your API require a valid session token in order to get data for a particular user? My concern would be that an attacker could simply use the API to get the data they wanted if you didn't have another layer of security in it. How would you secure your API to prevent this?

Comment: Any application is only as secure as it's codebase is and in this approach you artificially increase the size of the codebase with no apparent gain.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, I wouldn't necessarily say there is no apparent gain. If you were to restrict your API only to active sessions, you would be able to prevent someone retrieving all database data from the web server.

Comment: I don't see how you came from claim to conclusion in above comment.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, care to clarify what you mean? I think the basis of the conclusion is pretty clear, but would be happy to explain further if you need clarification.

Comment: What does "limiting to active sessions" (what does that mean at all?) have to do with retrieving all data. I'm able to retrieve any data from any API as long as it doesn't limit my ability to do so, but it's not a merit of API's in themselves. You can have exactly the same with a web app, you can either limit access to data or leave it open.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, that was one possible approach of preventing users from selecting all records from your database. Since they are on your site, they have a session ID. The API could require a session ID to authenticate a user and validate that they should be allowed to retrieve the data they are attempting to.

This would add a layer of security in the sense that if someone were to compromise my web server, they would only be capable of leveraging my API methods for active sessions. As such, it would prevent the attacker from breaching all of my data because they compromised the web server.

Comment: A lot of assumptions here and they're all quite optimistic I would say.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, are you going to provide any comments of value or continue to be snide and vague? If you have a claim, back it up with an alternative -- specifically identify the points you're refuting instead of posting sweeping generalizations. As it stands right now, you're acting like a jerk and doing the precise opposite of SO's "be nice" policy.

Comment: I am not vague. I am arguing that security of every system depends on the quality of code not on how many layers it has. Also, API server, even if secured from outside access, will rather be quite vulnerable if web app server gets compromised, right? So, as previously stated, I don't see any huge merit of multi layer in terms of security, but I will stress again it makes the system way more complicated, which may lead to security problems.

Comment: And if your data is so sensitive that you need to protect it very well maybe keeping it offline is the best choice? (like hot vs cold wallet for bitcoin)